# nativescript actionbar under status bar in android

Tags: android-actionbar, nativescript

I'm starting with Nativescript (javascript) and I have a problem with the action bar in android. 
When I create an action bar as follows:

```
    <Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">
      <Page.actionBar>
          <ActionBar title="My ActionBar"/>
      </Page.actionBar>

      <!-- page content ... -->
    </Page>
```

The action bar is created under the status bar of the phone (no css has been done):

[Action bar under the status bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvoR7.jpg)

1) Am I missing something or this is the normal behaviour?

2) Also the action bar size is much bigger than all the other app. Is the default height bigger than the standard?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The **Page** has a property called  [backgroundSpanUnderStatusBar](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_page_.page.html#backgroundspanunderstatusbar)to control whether the content can span under the status bar or not.

The size should be standard by default. Still, you can create c[ustom layout](http://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/ui/action-bar#setting-custom-title-view) for your action-bar or use a [CSS theme](http://docs.nativescript.org/ui/theme#actionbar)

Comment: Setting backgroundSpanUnderStatusBar = "false" does not solve the problem. Looking at some examples (https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-marketplace-demo) I see that in the app.android.css there is ActionBar {
    margin: 25 0 0 0;
} Without this, it will go under the status bar as in my case. I'm starting to think that this is the default behaviour.

Comment: On what API level you are experiencing this behaviour - I have made a basic project but was not able to reproduce and the action bar is rendered normally after the status bar (API 23+) Here is the project: https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-issues/tree/master/stack/actionBarStatusBar

Comment: Keep in mind that if you are using the marketplace demo as your project template it might cause your action bar to go under the status bar as there is a fullscreen launch-screen template used there specifically. If you, however, create new application using one of the base templates you action-bar won't go under

Comment: Your project works fine. Where can I check the API level? Thank you very much

Comment: I mean the API level of your testing device (emulator or real device).. however it is more probably another reason as I have already confirmed that with the default templates everything works on older API levels as well